# Java exception handling

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code. In that `fn2` is actually throwing an exception and it is caught in the function itself. In the function `fn1` the compiler is complaining about unhandled exception since `fn2` is declared to be throwing an Exception.

Why it is so? Since the exception is caught inside `fn2` it shouldn't be complaining right?

Please explain the behavior.

```
public class ExepTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExepTest exT = new ExepTest();
    exT.fn1();

}
public void fn1(){
    fn2();//compilation error
}
public void fn2() throws Exception{

    try{
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception caught");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compiler doesn't/can't know that at runtime no exception will be throwed by `fn2()` since it's declared that it may throw an Exception, that's why you got an error.

Comment: In other words: If you **tell it** that a methods `throws Exception` then the compiler will **believe you**. It won't check if that's actually the case (in some cases he can't even check).

Comment: @Joachim: It's a relationship based on mutual trust.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `throws Exception` from `fn2()` signature

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the method fn2 is all that matters here. In that signature you declare that fn2 may throw an Exception. Any code that calls a method that may throw an Exception must handle the eexception.

Answer (score 1):

`public void fn2() throws Exception`. The compiler see that declaration and expect each caller to `fn2` to handle / rethrow the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is thrown BY `fn2`, not inside it. So it will be actually thrown where it is called. Since it is called in `fn1`, it is behaving like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the call to `fn2()` in a try-catch block, or declare that `fn1` also throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void fn1(){
    fn2();//compilation error
}
public void fn2() throws Exception{

    try{
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception caught");
    }
}
}
```

Here compiler will not recognize that you have handled exception or not. It just assumes that fn2 throws exception as you have declared to be and that's why it's showing error.

To run program either *remove `throws Exception` from fn2* or *write `throws Exception` in fn1 or handle it in `try..catch` in fn1*.